# Cascade delete when combined column values are unique foreign key

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, cascading-deletes

I have the following tables:

[locations]
    id  PK
    title
    description

[floors]
    id  PK
    locationid  FK
    floorlevel
    description

[rooms]
    id  PK
    locationid  FK
    floorid     FK
    description

[features]
    id  PK
    title

[object_features]
    id  PK
    featureid   FK
    objectid    FK (linked to either [locations].id,[floors].id or [rooms].id)
    objectype   (value of 1=location, 2=floor, 3=room)

Now if location X is deleted from [locations] I want to delete related rooms and floors (yes rooms can also be related directly to a location and not through a floor), that's done easily with a cascade delete.

But each of the different object types (location, floor and room) can also have 0 or more features, which are stored in [object_features]
Meaning that [object_features].objectid and [object_features].objecttype might have the same value more than once, but it's a unique combination when combined with [object_features].featureid.

So when a location is deleted, I also want to delete all rows in [object_features] that are related to the rows deleted in [locations], [floors] and/or [rooms] because of that location X deletion.
I feel like I need to add some logic on each table ([locations],[floors],[rooms]) that takes action when a row is deleted. I feel like a trigger might do the trick, but am not sure if that's the recommended approach. And also am unsure how to implement it, an example would be great.

Already checked here: [CASCADE DELETE on two foreign key constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27558085/cascade-delete-on-two-foreign-key-constraints), but seems a different solution.

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[locations](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](500) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_homes] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO



CREATE TABLE [dbo].[location_floors](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [locationid] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_location_floors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_floors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_location_floors_locations] FOREIGN KEY([locationid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[locations] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_floors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_location_floors_locations]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[location_rooms](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [locationid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [floorid] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_location_rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_rooms]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_location_rooms_locations] FOREIGN KEY([locationid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[locations] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[location_rooms] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_location_rooms_locations]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[features](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [title] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_voorzieningen] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[features] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_voorzieningen_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[object_features](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [objectid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [objecttype] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [featureid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [createdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_location_voorzieningen] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[object_features] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_location_voorzieningen_createdate]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [createdate]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[object_features]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_object_features_features] FOREIGN KEY([featureid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[features] ([id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[object_features] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_object_features_features]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'1=location, 2=floor, 3=room' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'object_features', @level2type=N'COLUMN',@level2name=N'objecttype'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

An `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger may be used in SQL Server to perform a cascaded delete in cases where DRI isn't permitted due to multiple update paths.

Below is an example that performs the needed deletes in the proper order. Just follow a similar pattern for triggers on the other tables that need cascaded deletes.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_location_delete
ON dbo.locations
INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

--delete rooms for location
DELETE rooms
FROM dbo.rooms
JOIN dbo.floors ON floors.id = rooms.floorid
JOIN deleted ON deleted.id = rooms.floorid;

--delete floors for location
DELETE floors
FROM dbo.floors
JOIN deleted ON deleted.id = floors.locationid;

--delete location
DELETE locations
FROM dbo.locations
JOIN deleted ON deleted.id = locations.id;
GO
```

Comment: I've already configured cascade delete rules that uses the locationid to delete rooms and floors related to that locationid. From what I understand from your code, it's overriding the default cascade delete I've already setup, correct? The problem however I face is how to make sure that depending on from what table the row that's being deleted (locations,floors or rooms), to delete the related rows from [object_features]. I'm still unsure how to do that. Can you help?

Comment: The intent of this trigger is to perform the delete cascade instead of doing so via DRI. I don't think you can create the cascading foreign keys as specified in your textual description as that would cause multiple paths. Add the actual CREATE TABLE DDL with constraints to your question to clarify.

Comment: Added the DDL. If this is too complex, maybe I should create separate tables for object_features per objecttype? So object_features_locations, object_features_floors and object_features_rooms....is that perhaps also the best practice?